# What is autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay in autovacuum in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, autovacuum

I am trying to tweak the PostgreSQL server with the following config parameters in the configuration file:

```
autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 500000000
autovacuum_max_workers = 6
autovacuum_naptime = '15s'
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0
maintenance_work_mem = '10GB'
vacuum_freeze_min_age = 10000000
```

I want to understand what `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` does. I tried searching a lot on google but didn't get anything good enough to understand.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/10/tuning-autovacuum-in-postgresql-and-autovacuum-internals/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It says that "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay : autovacuum will sleep for these many milliseconds when a cleanup reaching autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit cost is done." and "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit" says that it's total cost limit autovacuum could reach (combined by all autovacuum jobs).

Can you please help me understand "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-COST-DELAY) refers to [`vacuum_cost_delay`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-VACUUM-COST-DELAY), which says:

> The amount of time that the process will sleep when the cost limit has been exceeded.

This is a feature to slow down autovacuum. Whenever an autovacuum worker does work (delete a tuple, read a block, ...), it collects work points. As soon as these points exceed `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` (200 by default), it makes a pause of
`autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`.

The reason is that `VACUUM` uses a lot of resources, so it is slowed down by default, in the hope not to be disruptive to normal operation. However, if autovacuum is too slow, you can end up with bloated tables.

Comment: Great, so using autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0 is okay to use with large DBs?

Comment: Yes - it will create more load during autovacuum, but jobs will get done faster.